# Why is multiplication much more ubiquitous than addition in physics?

Tags: units, dimensional-analysis

This may sound shamefully naive, but I have no good explanation. My only guess would be that multiplication is much less "demanding" to be included in formulae, due to the fact that addition demands that the things being summed have the same units, but *I don't even know why that is*, other than the fact that you can't do it in the same way that $x + y$ cannot be explicitly solved like multiplication could be, with $x * y$ being $xy$ solved.

However, multiplication is *repeated* addition, which sounds intuitively *more* niche, let's say, but is much easier to put in a formula. Multiplication can successfully compute an explicit answer with two things with different dimensions despite being derivative of addition, while addition cannot. I simply don't understand why this is the case. I'm sure the explanation to this cannot be explained quickly, but any kind of explanation would help.

Comment: Who says that addition is uncommon? And what does "more ubiquitous" even mean? Where does one calibrate ubiquitometers, and why are you so sure that yours is calibrated correctly?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty By "more ubiquitous", I mean if I were to write down all the equations and relationships I've learned studying physics and counted the number of addition symbols and asterisks (or implied multiplications, like $xy$), multiplication as an operation would dominate in frequency.

Comment: Keep in mind that addition is so common and automatic that we often neglect to even mention it. What's the mass of an extended object—why it's the **sum** of the masses of the constituent parts (well, up until relativity rears it's head, anyway). But we rarely bother to talk about.

Comment: Remember also that integrals are essentially sums. Not, of course, that I find this sort of "weighing" between two operations that are both used in different contexts in any way productive.

Comment: In log space — and most things in the Universe are logarithmically distributed — multiplication becomes addition.

Comment: @sangstar That's the thing: "the equations I've learned". What about the (infinite) set of relations you *haven't* learned? How can you say anything useful about an infinite set without sampling, and how could you possibly tell whether your sampling is biased?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about any concept of physics, but about how physics is written down and represented.

Answer (score 1):

It's only more common at the introductory level. When you get more advanced, it's all about derivatives (subtraction and division paired with a [limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_(mathematics))) and integrals (multiplication and addition paired with a limit). Most places you see multiplication in physics my instinct is to look for the underlying integral or derivative being papered over. In other words, the multiplication you see is a result of simplifying the study of rates of change (with respect to time, position, or etc) of things.

For example, the kinematics formula
$$x = x_0 + v_0 t + \frac{1}{2} a t^2$$
is, in reality, just what you get when you plug constant acceleration into the definition of acceleration and integrating twice. The definition of acceleration is the rate of change of velocity,
$$a = \frac{\operatorname{d}v}{\operatorname{d}t},$$
and velocity is the rate of change of position,
$$v = \frac{\operatorname{d}x}{\operatorname{d}t},$$
and combining those two definitions says that acceleration is the curvature in position,
$$a = \frac{\operatorname{d}^2x}{\operatorname{d}t^2}.$$
Inverting this gives,
\begin{align}
   x &= \int_0^t \left(\int_0^{t'} a(t'') \operatorname{d}t''\right) \operatorname{d}t' \\
& = \int_0^t \left(v_0 + a t'\right) \operatorname{d}t'\\
& = x_0 + v_0t + \frac{1}{2} at^2,
\end{align}
if $a$ is a constant. If not, the integrals have to be modified.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplication/division is more common than addition/subtraction because multiplication can do useful things with multiple dimensions whole addition is stuck with only one. Your definition of multiplication as "repeated addition" is only complete in a numerical, abstract sense. In the physical world multiplication is both more useful and more nuanced.

Let's say you're working on a fluid flow problem. With addition, you can measure the apparatus and obtain a total flow path length in cm and that's about it. But with multiplication you can calculate the cross-sectional area in cm^2 of the pipe, the volume cm^3 of the contained fluid, the flow speed m/s of the fluid, the mass flow rate kg m/s... not even counting the electrical requirements of the pump, the strength characteristics of the materials, and countless other properties relevant to the physics or engineering of the project.

Since real world problems typically involve proportions and deal with more than one dimension or quality at a time, multiplication is necessary to solve most problems. Addition by itself is *only* useful for finding sums of like-dimensioned quantities, and even those are not always physically meaningful.